# How to perform action on parts of a downloaded file

Tags: bash, shell, ftp

Apologies for the title of the question but I'm. It sure how to best summarise this. Basically I have very large text files hosted on a server. I don't have the capacity to download the entire file. I have a shell script that I want to run on individual lines of the text file. Is there a way of (ftp) downloading chunks of the file and performing the shell script on this chunk and then downloading the next chunk (preferably overwriting the preceding one) to perform the shell script etc.

Comment: Do you really need FTP? is SSH available? [FTP must die](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `curl` in `FTP` mode by changing the output to `stdout` rather than a local filename and then using `dd` or `head` or `tail` to get at the data.

The following connects via FTP to my localhost and gets the file `<HOME>/tmp/ppm.c` and then uses `dd` to set the blocksize to `1k` and skip the first block, writing the output to the file `2nd1kB.txt`.

```
curl --output - --user user:password 'ftp://127.0.0.1/tmp/ppm.c' | dd bs=1024 skip=1 count=1 > 2nd1kB.txt
```

If you want multiple blocks, you will need a loop. Here I just loop from 0 to 3:

```
#!/bin/bash
for block in {0..3}; do
   echo Grabbing block $block
   curl --silent --output - --user user:password 'ftp://127.0.0.1/tmp/ppm.c' | dd bs=100 count=1 skip=$block > Block${block}.txt
done
```

Comment: So does this then download the second and third block? How would I download subsequent blocks?

Comment: I have updated to show how to do a few blocks in a loop. I am actually saving each block in a different file to demonstrate the technique. I guess you will want to overwrite the previous file, so your command will end in `dd bs=100 count=1 skip=$block > block.txt`